# corona storyboard dispatch event error

Tags: coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am getting the below error in corona simulator. Nothing has changed in my files that I know of. ( I have included the main.lua code and the menuMain.lua code.) If you have any ideas on what might be causing this would be appricated! =) thanks.

---

Corona Simulator Runtime Error
File: ?
Attempt to call method 'dispatchEvent' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
[c] in function 'dispatchEvent'
? in funciton gotoScene
...dwegrecki/main.lua:16 in main chunck

---

-- main.lua

```
-- Hide Status Bar
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

-- require controller module
local storyboard = require "storyboard"

-- load first screen
storyboard.gotoScene( "menuMain" )
```

-- menuMain.lua

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    local mainBg
    local titleIcon
    local startBtn
    local aboutBtn
    local onStartBtnTouch = {}
    local scene = {}


    -- Touch event listener for startBtn
local function onStartBtnTouch( self, event )
        if event.phase == "began" then
        storyboard.gotoScene( "menuLevel", "fade", 400  )
            return true
        end
end

    -- Touch event listener for cerditsBtn
local function onCreditsBtnTouch( self, event )
        if event.phase == "began" then
        storyboard.gotoScene( "zerocredits", "fade", 400  )
            return true 
        end
end

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view

    mainBg = display.newImage('bg.png')
    titleBg = display.newImage('title.png', 0, 100)
    playBtn = display.newImage('playBtn.png', 200, 240)
    creditsBtn = display.newImage('creditsBtn.png', 200, 290)
    titleView = display.newGroup(titleBg, playBtn, creditsBtn)

    screenGroup:insert( titleBg, playBtn, creditsBtn )

    playBtn.touch = onStartBtnTouch
    creditsBtn.touch = onCreditsBtnTouch

end

-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    print( "1: enterScene event" )

    -- remove previous scene's view
    storyboard.purgeScene( "LevelMenu" )
    storyboard.purgeScene( "credits" )
    storyboard.purgeScene("main")

end

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    print( "1: exitScene event" )

    -- remove touch listener for image
    mainBg:removeEventListener( "touch", mainBg )
end

-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    print( "((destroying scene 1's view))" )
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recreate same project like your's and i'm getting an error on `local scene = {}` why did you make the variable scene a table ?

Comment: Thanks DevfaR Just so you know that along with the fact that I used a credits.lua file were causing problems. I changed the credits.lua file name and I also fixed the local scene = {} and everything is working great!!

Comment: @AziDesigns... man you just saved  me a lot of effort! I also had a credits.lua file that was causing the issue. New to lua/corona, so probably would not have figured that out for a long while. Cheers.